# Copying unique files to a new location

Tags: bash

I am a total newbie to Linux and bash scripting and am currently stumped with this problem!

I have a directory containing many images from which I need to copy the unique images to a new location.  I know there are numerous options for how to go about doing this but have very limited knowledge at the moment so appreciate I may be going about this the wrong way.

I used find and cat to create this list and have attempted to copy the files across with the intention of comparing them (using md5 and checking file names) when they are there.

However, the text file has 30 files on it but only 18 have been copied over.  Can anyone advise?

My code to find files is -

```
find $1 -name "IMG_****.JPG" | cat > list.txt
```

and my code to copy from the list is

```
for image in $(cat list.txt);
do
cp $image $2
done
```

Comment: Did you get any errors? This should either work or display errors...

Comment: Topical reading: [ParsingLS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by `"IMG_****.JPG"`?  That matches `IMG_.JPG` as well as `IMG_abcde123.JPG`.  Is that your intent?  If so, just use `IMG_*.JPG` for clarity.  If you actually want only files with 4 characters between `_` and `.`, use `IMG_????.JPG`.  See [the man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-pathname-expansion) for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing this much too complicated. Do not pipe `find` output to `cat` to pipe it into a list. This is an unnecessary use of `cat`. If you must, you can redirect the output of every program directly:

```
find "$1" -name "IMG_*.JPG" > list.txt
```

Also, [do not use `for` to read lines from a file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Better [use `while` with `read`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
while read -r filename; do
    cp "$filename" "$2"
done < list.txt
```

**But it's even easier.** You can just work with the files directly from `find`:

```
find "$1" -name "IMG_*.JPG" -exec cp {} "$2" \;
```

Here, `{}` will be replaced by each filename that `find` finds. Don't forget to [quote your variables](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting), so that spaces in file paths are no problem.

Another much simpler method with Bash options:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
cp -t "$2" -- "$1"/**/IMG_*.JPG
```

Here, `globstar` enables recursive matching of directories through `**`. The `-t` option to `cp` specifies the target of the copy operation.* The command will be expanded to `cp -t target -- source1/IMG_foo.JPG source2/IMG_bar.JPG` et cetera.

---

Now, as to your original issue, it could have been that some images have a space in their name. This would have broken your original script. If your image files contained a newline in their name, it also wouldn't have worked with `while read …` – but you would have gotten an error in that case of a file not being found.

Also note that `cp` overwrites files with the same name. Without asking for confirmation. So if in your subdirectories there are images with the same filename, you'd only get one result, with the latest overwriting the existing one.

<sub>* The `--` isn't strictly necessary, but it's a good habit to include it to tell the command when the options arguments are over.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I'm still getting to grips with the capabilities of the various commands!

Comment: @user2846121 Sure. If the issue isn't that the images are overwritten (because your file contained 30 lines and there are only 18 copied over), then it'd be weird, but I have no other explanation at the moment. Maybe you can then show us the output of the `find` command itself, without the `exec` part.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf A viable suggestion. Globs are still totally underrated. Although I don't know if the OP has nested directories, so a `"$1"/**/IMG_*.JPG` may be in order with `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: I don't think I will be able to use the globstar query as there are some named images I don't want to copy.  I tried using the while loop but have the same problem with the number of files.  I'm going to try and sort the images before I copy them over as there are some identically named files which have different images and vice versa.